# Jquery PHP Form

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax

I have a link on my page that loads the div using a jquery function. On the page there is a form that submits to a database. The form works when when I type the page in directly but when the function loads the page, the form doesn't work.

```
$('.menu_top').click(function() {
var href = $(this).attr('href');
$('#load').hide().load(href).fadeIn('normal');
return false
```

});

This is what I am using to load the page into the div. I have added the class to the form and button. When I click submit the page flashes but the SQL doesnt update

Comment: Can you make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) showing your html and JS?

Comment: There are no answers and comments because we don't understand your problem. Clarify, what is your problem + as Kevin said, better to create fiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zn8Ex/ is this okay?

Comment: What is the "action" of your form?

Comment: There is no action, everything happens on the one page

Answer (score 0):

When you load something into doom, you need to use the on command. Try this:

```
$('body').on('click','.menu_top',function() {
```